# how to fade to white some image texture shader?

Tags: shaders

i want to make shader by nodes that look like Voile curtain. but i need to make it looks like this photo.[image]

but ways i tried made this result. [image]

how can i do this fading to white?

Comment: Use a gradient texture. Once you get the coordinates right, the rest is easy.

Comment: Since rotate gradient is not that easy use Texture Coordinate node and Separate XYZ node to use Z as factor for Mix RGB node http://www.blenderinsight.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/word-image-405.png

Comment: @vklidu and use my image connected to Diffuse bsdf color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As usual with nodes, there is more than one way to do this:

[image]

Here, I am using the Y position of the UV coordinates as the factor to mix my texture color into white.

I am also using an RGB curves node to distort these coordinates to control the exact gradient.  Not asked for, but recommended.

Many people would use a (possibly remapped) gradient texture instead of separated UV.Y.  A linear gradient texture just outputs the X component of the input vector; using coords or a linear gradient amounts to the exact same thing.  Many people would use a color ramp instead of an RGB curves node, but I find the curves interface easier to use.

There are alternate coordinates that you can use.  For most objects, generated coordinates describe the 0,1 bounding box of the object, so you could probably use generated coordinates.z instead of UV.y.  I usually prefer to use UV coordinates over other coordinates for editability and stability.

Comment: it worked really well. thanks so much